# when I try to update "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade", an error related to rabbitmq comes out

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, sudo, rabbitmq

```
Hit:1 ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Get:2 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5,185 B]
Hit:3 ://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Hit:4 ://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease            
Hit:5 ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:6 ://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Get:7 ://dl.modular.com/public/installer/deb/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5,076 B]
Get:8 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5,182 B]
Get:9 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [109 kB]
Get:10 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5,185 B]
Hit:11 ://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:12 ://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Hit:13 ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease             
Hit:14 ://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 InRelease
Ign:15 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Err:15 https://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Get:16 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5,182 B]
Hit:17 ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease           
Ign:15 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Err:15 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Get:18 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [13.7 kB]
Ign:19 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Err:19 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Ign:20 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Get:21 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [109 kB]
Ign:19 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Err:20 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Err:19 ://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Ign:20 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Get:22 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [13.7 kB]
Ign:23 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Err:20 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Err:23 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Ign:23 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
Err:23 ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
Fetched 5,076 B in 3s (1,993 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository '://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa2.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
E: Failed to fetch ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
E: Failed to fetch ://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.140.63 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want this problem to disappear, this problem appear every time I want to update or upgrade

Comment: You've added an invalid source to your system, the fix is to remove (or disable it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: How can I remove it or disable?